# Check database connections

Tags: sql-server

Long story short, we import data from a firebird database to MS SQL, this is imported to a backup database, checks are done to ensure all is well, then the names are switched, so it becomes the live database.

To do this we set the db to single user, sp_renamedb, then set it back to multi-user.

Periodically, this can fail if there is an open connection to either of the DBs. I have adapted the below script, this is to find any connections to the databases in question.

I just want to make sure this is a reliable way to get any connections? Once I have them, I can decide what to do with them.

```
SELECT      DB_NAME(SP.dbid)        AS  Database_name                       ,
            SP.spid                 AS  SPIDS                               ,
            SP.hostname             AS  HostName                            ,
            SP.loginame             AS  LoginID                             
FROM        sys.sysprocesses        AS  SP
WHERE       (
            DB_NAME(SP.dbid)        =   'Database1'
OR          DB_NAME(SP.dbid)        =   'Database2'
            )   
GROUP BY    DB_NAME(SP.dbid)                                                ,
            SP.spid                                                         ,
            SP.hostname                                                     ,
            SP.loginame
ORDER BY    DB_NAME(SP.dbid);
```

Cheers

Comment: Looks good to me. I tested your code on my instance and made connections to two databases and they both showed up in the query you wrote. Not sure if you're looking for something else (I only have one instance, and I'm the only one who can connect, so it's not "foolproof", which is why I didn't put this as an answer) but your code definitely works.

Comment: Looks fine except the group by, never seen duplicate spid in sys.sysprocesses since only one process can run at a time per session.

Comment: Thanks both, appreciate the feedback.